# Can't Upload Image using WordPress Media Upload

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, debian

I'm trying to upload an image to my WordPress site. The image is 5.6 MB big.
The resolution is 1920px x 1444px.

I've already uploaded a much smaller image (0.5MB / 939px x 471px). That worked fine.

**I'm getting this error message**: The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels.
[image: Error Message that I get. You can see that the upload size = 128M]

---

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I have already tried a few things:

1. Changed the `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `max_execution_time` in the *php.ini* File
   (WordPress even says that the max size is 128M now)
2. Changed the '`big_image_size_threshold`'
3. Uploaded the images to the Server via SFTP, renamed them according to the Other images that are in the Folder, but that didnt work as well
4. Installed a few plug-ins that change the max upload size. Didnt work either.

I've looked at so many websites, but they all gave me these as solutions.

Has anybody got any Idea? Thank you in advance.

---

WHAT I AM USING:

Operating System: **Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)**
PHP-Version: **8.0**
WordPress Version: **6.1.1**

Also I'm using Nginx not Apache2

Dean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try deactivating all other plugins temporarily; it may happen sometimes due to some plugin processing the images before uploading them to the server.
2. If you want to upload any file to the WordPress outside the WordPress dashboard, make sure to use the plugin named "[Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/)"; for this case, you first upload your file to the directory then you import them via this plugin to your WordPress database so it loads in the WordPress dashboard.
3. Last, if you are using a control panel to manage your server, check the `php.ini` setting in its control panel; sometimes settings in the server overwrite the local `php.ini` in your website directory.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was:
**Install and activate the WordPress plugin “Disable ‘BIG Image’ Threshold” plugin.**

in my situation I was able to upload images, but i got error on every image, and what was interesting: that image was saved to gallery. May be my solution will help somebody.